# Different user other than "USER root" in Dockerfile while executing crucial "RUN apt-get..." commands

Tags: docker, root, non-root-user, chown

I recently experienced a Mass Email attack where someone "sniffed" my email and was using it as a "From:myemail@email.com" in the mass attack.

I believe my email info get sniffed because I enabled IMAP, used SSL instead of TLS, among other things. But I also got lazy with root user in my dockerfile.

I'm a data engineer and not a linux pro. I'm sharing a dockerfile that I'm extending from apache-airflow after running a build command. **Can you please help me do something other than "USER root" below? How can I make everything just the "myuser"?**

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest
COPY --chown=myuser:root requirements.txt /
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vim
RUN apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER myuser
ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/python:...
RUN export PATH=$PATH:$PYTHONPATH
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt
```

I tried to remove the chown and start with "USER myuser" instead of root, but I got a permission denied error when trying to run the first "RUN apt-get..." commands.

Comment: You don't need to, the last USER is all that's effective in the final container. You must apt-get as root and this will not be the source of your information escape.

Comment: By the way... the "RUN rm -rf" does not shrink you image. You need to join all those RUN commands into one using "&". each RUN command creates a layer and later layers just black out deleted files, they done remove them from the final image.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipCouling. Good input. I concatenated the RUN with "&&" in one run command. Thanks for the input. Seems like the rest largely stays the same.

Comment: This Dockerfile has absolutely nothing to do with the spam blowback problem at the beginning of your question. Quite likely neither does your use of a weaker cipher over IMAP, though that's harder to rule out. (If somebody was able to sniff your email, they would also have sniffed your password if it was communicated in the clear, which is a much more valuable asset.)

Comment: Thanks @tripleee. That's what my quick research is leading me to. Thanks for sharing your input.

Comment: A possible workaround, which however still briefly requires root privileges, would be to install `sudo` and add `myuser` to `sudoers`; then this account can perform upgrades with `sudo` privileges. But this does not seem to really buy you anything, it just pushes the problem to a different, and arguably more obscure corner (if indeed there is a problem, which I don't think there really is).

Comment: You could split this into two separate build stages where the first builds an image which just installs `sudo` and adds the account with the necessary privileges; then use this image as your `FROM` image. But again, I cannot see that this really solves any actual problem.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee. Even though my knowledge is limited in info sec, I do believe the root/sudo user solves the actual email sniffing problem. But I do like your recommendations. I'll have to figure out how to add a myuser to sudoers. While I've used the sudo command before, I have yet to govern sudo access. I'll try this.

Comment: If your platform is Debian-nased, just `addgroup myuser sudoers`. On some other platforms you probably have to edit the `sudoers` configuration file.